# Dynamic programming algorithm to find palindromes in a directed acyclic graph

Tags: dynamic-programming, graph-theory, graph-algorithm, palindrome

The problem is as follows: given a directed acyclic graph, where each node is labeled with a character, find all the longest paths of nodes in the graph that form a palindrome.

The initial solution that I thought of was to simply enumerate all the paths in the graph. This effectively generates a bunch of strings, on which we can then apply [Manacher's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_palindromic_substring) to find all the longest palindromes. However, this doesn't seem that efficient, since the amount of paths in a graph is exponential in the number of nodes.

Then I started thinking of using dynamic programming directly on the graph, but my problem is that I cannot figure out how to structure my "dynamic programming array". My initial try was to use a 2d boolean array, where array[i][j] == true means that node i to node j is a palindrome but the problem is that there might be multiple paths from i to j.

I've been stuck on this problem for quite a while now I can't seem to figure it out, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linear-time trick of Manacher's algorithm relies on the fact that if you know that the longest palindrome centered at character 15 has length 5 (chars 13-17), and there's a palindrome centered at node 19 of length 13 (chars 13-25), then you can skip computing the longest palindrome centered at character 23 (23 = 19 + (19 - 15)) because you know it's just going to be the mirror of the one centered at character 15.

With a DAG, you don't have that kind of guarantee because the palindromes can go off in any direction, not just forwards and backwards. However, if you have a candidate palindrome path from node `m` to node `n`, whether you can extend that string to a longer palindrome doesn't depend on the path between `m` and `n`, but only on `m` and `n` (and the graph itself).

Therefore, I'd do this:

First, [sort the graph nodes topologically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting), so that you have an array `s[]` of node indexes, and there being an edge from `s[i]` to `s[j]` implies that `i < j`.

I'll also assume that you build up an inverse array or hash structure `sinv[]` such that `s[sinv[j]] == j` and `sinv[s[n]] == n` for all integers `j` in `0..nodeCount-1` and all node indexes `n`.

Also, I'll assume that you have functions `graphPredecessors`, `graphSuccessors`, and `graphLetter` that take a node index and return the list of predecessors on the graph, the list of successors, or the letter at that node, respectively.

Then, make a two-dimensional array of integers of size `nodeCount` by `nodeCount` called `r`. When `r[i][j] = y`, and `y` > 0, it will mean that if there is a palindrome path from a successor of `s[i]` to a predecessor of `s[j]`, then that path can be extended by adding `s[i]` to the front and `s[j]` to the back, and that the extension can be continued by `y` more nodes (including `s[i]` and `s[j]`) in each direction:

```
for (i=0; i < nodeCount; i++) {
  for (j=i; j < nodeCount; j++) {
    if (graphLetter(s[i]) == graphLetter(s[j])) {
      r[i][j] = 1;
      for (pred in graphPredecessors(s[i])) {
        for (succ in graphSuccessors(s[j])) {
          /* note that by our sorting, sinv[pred] < i <= j < sinv[succ] */
          if (r[sinv[pred]][sinv[succ]] >= r[i][j]) {
            r[i][j] = 1 + r[sinv[pred]][sinv[succ]];
          }
        }
      }
    } else {
      r[i][j] = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Then find the maximum value of `r[x][x]` for `x` in `0..nodeSize-1`, and of `r[lft][rgt]` where there is an edge from `s[lft]` to `s[rgt]`. Call that maximum value `M`, and say you found it at location `[i][j]`. Each such `i`, `j` pair will represent the center of a longest palindrome path. As long as `M` is greater than `1`, you then extend each center by finding a `pred` in `graphPredecessors(s[i])` and a `succ` in `graphSuccessors(s[j])` such that `r[sinv[pred]][sinv[succ]] == M - 1` (the palindrome is now `pred`->`s[i]`->`s[j]`->`succ`). You then extend that by finding the appropriate index with an `r` value of `M - 2`, etc., stopping when you reach a spot where the value in `r` is `1`.

I think this algorithm overall ends up with a runtime of `O(V^2 + E^2)`, but I'm not entirely certain of that.